# unable to start recyclerviewactivity from any other activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am unable to start recyclerviewactivity from any other activity. any help?.I can launch any other activity but not recyclerviewactivity. Is there some additional params required?

Comment: Can you post your code which you are trying?

Comment: you need to show code for anyone to help

Comment: maybe you are forgetting to add that activity to your manifest.
provide some code please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set adapter(RecyclerView.Adapter) to recyclerView in your class? 
e.g.-

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(this, itemList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

& if it doesn't solve your issue then, please add java class where you are having problem.